# SFDX force:source:convert and deployment won't push up new components

Tags: salesforcedx, managed-package, deployment, metadata-api

I was following the Trailhead for Updating and Deploying my Managed Package.

I am a bit confused though on how exactly I'm supposed to deploy.

I'm at the point where I have my Package org and my Dev Hub org. I created the app as it tells me to in the trailhead and I need to convert back to meta data so I can deploy it. So I run the command

`sfdx force:source:convert -d mdapi-source/updated-package -n "MyManagedPackage"`

I get no errors. I check my files. I have the metadata files in my `force-app/main/default` folder and in my `mdapi-source/updated-package` it looks like i have the regular non-metadata files and my package.xml file looks correct and the name is correct.

So how do I deploy? When I try running the deploy command nothing happens. I go back to my package org, I do not see the new components.

I've tried this process by authing into all the orgs (dev hub, package, scratch) and no change happens. Is there a step I missed?

Comment: I presume you are referring to this [trailhead:step](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/first_generation_managed_packages/update_and_deploy_you_package) and you ran `sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -d mdapi-source/updated-package -u PkgOrg -l RunLocalTests -w 15`  as per instructions?  I just did this TH a week ago and it worked fine

Comment: hello @cropredy, yeah i did run that command. it does show MDAPI Progress and i get to 8/8. The problem is when I try to convert nothing happens?